# How to replace odd separators from a csv file to something else using python regex?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-re

I have a csv file. The third column can contain odd separators like this:

```
Name,Last Name,Job,ID
John,Smith,Architect,ID2020
Taylor,Swift,Singer,Songwriter,ID2020-123
```

I know that the third column can some times be faulty, also next column always starts with ID. The odd comma is between singer and songwriter. How can I replace the odd comma with lets say tilda, so it would be possible to read the file using pandas without errors? The actual file has 30 columns, so regular expressions are probably way to go. Thanks for your time.

Comment: you can use `my_string.replace(',','~')` where you load the whole file with `import csv` on `my_string`

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem because it would replace all commas to ~, in the example I need to replace only 1 comma between singer and songwriter.

Comment: you haven't specified that. Please write your question in a better way with an example of what you want to achive. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It seems to me that what you want to do is this: If a line has fewer than 4 commas, leave it alone. If it has 4 or more commas, replace the 3rd comma with something else. If you approach it from that direction, it is not complicated to write a preprocessor to fix the file. But do print a warning message if a line has fewer than 3 or more than 4. Experience suggests your data may not be quite as regular as you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following approach:

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = []

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)
    
    for row in csv_input:
        data.append([*row[:2], ' '.join(row[2:-1]), row[-1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
print(df)
```

For your example, this gives:

```
     Name Last Name                    Job          ID
0    John     Smith              Architect      ID2020
1  Taylor     Swift      Singer Songwriter  ID2020-123
```

This assumes the unwanted commas are only in the Job column. It takes the `Name` and `Last Names` fields, then combines all fields until the last `ID` field. So in effect the `Job` field can have any number of commas.

This will need to be tweaked depending where all the other columns go.

Comment: Thanks. My data is more complex than I showed in the example. So it required some tinkering, but it worked in the end.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, try:

```
with open("original.csv") as infile:
    rows = infile.read().splitlines()

with open("output.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for row in rows:
        name, lname, *rest = row.split(",")
        job = "~".join(rest[:-1])
        ID = rest[-1]
        outfile.write(f"{name},{lname},{job},{ID}\n")

df = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
>>> df
     Name Last Name                Job          ID
0    John     Smith          Architect      ID2020
1  Taylor     Swift  Singer~Songwriter  ID2020-123
```

Answer (score 1):

The other "standard" way to separate columns in CSV files is using the semicolon.

The logic below does some string handling to split and rejoin, using the semicolon for the rejoining...

```py
with open("somefile.csv") as infile:
    data = infile.read().splitlines()


with open("someotherfile.csv", "w") as outfile:
    for row in data:
        splitrow = row.split(",")
        if len(splitrow) > 4:
            splitrow[2] = f"{splitrow[2]},{splitrow.pop(3)}"
        outfile.write(";".join(splitrow)+'\n')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("someotherfile.csv", sep=';')
print(df)
```

output

```
     Name Last Name                Job          ID
0    John     Smith          Architect      ID2020
1  Taylor     Swift  Singer,Songwriter  ID2020-123
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do it like this, going through line by line in the textfile.
"also every column starts with ID" do you want it to be just the number ? I removed the ID in every row in my solution.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open("input_list.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        name, lname, *job, ID = line.strip().split(",")
        d["Name"].append(name)
        d["Last Name"].append(lname)
        d["Job"].append(" ".join(job))
        d["ID"].append(ID[2:])

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print(df)

    Name    Last Name   Job                ID
0   John    Smith       Architect          2020
1   Taylor  Swift       Singer Songwriter  2020-123
```